# How to add extension target with specified configuration in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode

My project has four types of configurations: debug, release, debug_ent, and release_ent. I now want to add an extra extension target to my app, but I only want it to work in debug and release configurations. How can I achieve this?

I have successfully added the target to my app, and I noticed that the build phase has changed. However, I'm unsure about the next steps. What should I do next to proceed?